# Vlookup in an already filled column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in r containing products and their production year. Based on this production year I can calculate how old the product is, therefore I need this column to be always full.
Unfortunatly the data is not very clean, therefore for some weekdays the production year is missing (it's 0).

As the production year is always the same I am looking for a function like this:
If you find another row with exactly the same String in column C (Product), but column D (Production_Year) is different, calculate the maximum of the production year (so that it takes the year instead of the 0) and copy this maximum in the other row that had the 0 value.

Do you know how I can do that?
See the picture as reference.

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r5AW.png)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Also show the expected output for the same. Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If your data are in a data frame called `data`, you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
    group_by(Product) %>% 
    mutate(Production_Year = max(Production_Year, na.rm=TRUE))
```